# Weird DateTime ToString behavior in Dynamically generated MSIL

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I need something to build dynamically property retrieval methods at runtime and to execute fast, so I developed a solution using `Reflection Emit`:

```
public static void Func(string properyName, A obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("PropertyExtractor", typeof(string), new[] { typeof(A) }, type, true);
    var ilGen = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
    var getMethod = type.GetMethod($"get_{properyName}");
    var property = type.GetProperty(properyName);

    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, type);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getMethod);
    var toStringMethod = property.PropertyType.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, toStringMethod);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    var @delegate = (F)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(F));
    var a = @delegate(obj);
}

public delegate string F(A obj); 

public abstract class A 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
} 

public class B : A 
{ 
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is the code to invoke it:

```
var obj = new B
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "SomeName",
    Timestamp = DateTime.Today
};

Func("Timestamp", obj);
```

This is just for testing that's why it is in a method named `Func` with parameter of type `A`, etc.
As you can see you give it the name of the property and the instance and it creates a delegate to retrieve the string value of the property in that particular instance. Everything works fine until there is a `DateTime`. I test with `DateTime.Now` assigned to a property and every time I run the function i get weird values like: [image]
i tried to put a IFormatProvider just in case - same results.
.NET version is 4.7.1, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code does not compile... Is A a generic argument? is F another Generic argument?

Comment: public delegate string F(A obj); and A is the class: public abstract class A
     {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }
     }

     public class B : A
     {
      public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
     }

Comment: Can you please add this to your original post? Also, show the actual invocation of Func that produces the result you are showing.

Comment: Is this how you call Func? var b = new B();
 b.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
 
 Func("Timestamp", b);

Comment: If I run your code I get: "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program" on the line `var a = @delegate(obj);`...

Comment: Strange, cause I am executing it and everything is fine, except the value of the result. I copy pasted what I gave you in the post and it is working

Comment: I also have the "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program" error in LinqPad

Comment: For the record I am using Linqpad 4 to run this code.

Comment: I haven't tried with LINQPad, i am using VS 2017 Enterprise, so I suggest to use VS 2017

Comment: Same error with VS2017 Enterprise running  .net 4.7.1. Is it a Console app? Have you tried the sample you provided?

Comment: Of course I tried it in a ConsoleApp before posting it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. DateTime is a value type and ToString requires an address to be loaded onto the evaluation stack, not a value. When I added a local variable of the time and added the instructions to store the value in the local variable and then load the address of that variable it was resolved. Thanks to everyone that responded.

Comment: Good job on finding your answer. It might be worth putting the code yo used successfully into this answer in case people come along and think "But I don't know how to do that".